# function inside function inside function, Call to undefined function

Tags: php, function

Is this possible in php? I am kind of new and learning.

```
//file name: functions.php:
<?php
function addItem(){
...does something
// calls for another function in the same functions.php file
randomNumber();
}

function randomNumber(){
//generates random number
}

//////////////////////////////////////
file name: worker.php
<?php
//calls for addItem() function 
addItem();
...

function addItem(){
//calls for randomNumber() function
....
$itemId = randomNumber();
.....
}
```

so i keep getting the error: Call to undefined function randomNumber()
because i don't include the functions.php file in the addItem() function,
But if i include it, I keep geting the Cannot redeclare firstFunctionOnFunctionsFile() cus I already declare it.

any ideas?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Change the names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling function not defined. randomNumber function should be before addItem since you calling the function in:

```
//file name: functions.php:
<?php

function randomNumber(){
//generates random number
}


function addItem(){
// calls for another function in the same functions.php file but set before
randomNumber();
}
```

Different between require and include is include don't return any error that would stop the script running if required file don't exist. Also, require_once will check if the file has already been included, and if so, not include (require) it again

```
//file name: worker.php
<?php
require_once 'functions.php';
//generating new items and set return in a value
$newitem = addItem();
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the documentation for [include_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) and [require_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php), they allow you to include a file only one time regardless of how many times you call those functions, which prevent the errors you're seeing.

Also think about when and where you are doing your includes. Does it really make sense to include files within a function body? If you have a functions.php file that contains a number of functions you will need in your worker.php file, just include it at the head of worker.php so you don't have to worry about it later on in your code. This also makes it easier to see at a glance what different files are being included.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I did tried to use the include_once to include the functions.php but i keept geting the same cannot redeclare function.  The functions.php is included in the worker.php file    If i dont include the functions file in the function, it wont see the function. I dont think php can see the included functions outside a function